# Ordered sets. Chain upper bounds.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose I have an ordered set $A$ and a chain $B\subseteq A$ then does $B$ necessarily have a supremum? Let alone an upper bound? And if it is empty? 
This question is a bit confusing because I am not sure if I am expected to prove a classic case or to notice little cases in which the claim isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbb{N}$ with its usual ordering. Does the chain $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ have a supremum?

Comment: Less trivial example: Take the even integers in $\Bbb N$.